# How to make props stateful/ how to get updated props from root config to child apps in single spa react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, micro-frontend, single-spa

I have a single spa application where I am using 3 child apps (each being a micro-frontend). For 1 child app, I am mounting onto the root html and setting in always active status. For the rest 2, basing on the routes, will mount/un-mount themselves onto the root html. For the child that is always active, I am passing the current path as prop from the root so that basing on the path, components within that child should render (conditional rendering). The issue I am facing is, child is able to receive the prop from the root but when the path changes, the new path is not getting reflected into the child and I have to reload the page manually in-order to conditional render those components within that child app. So, here are the root-config.js files and child.js files.

```
**root-config.js**

import { registerApplication, start } from "single-spa";
registerApplication({
  name: "@mrc/app1",
  app: () => System.import("@mrc/app1"),
  activeWhen: ["/app1", (location) => location.pathname.startsWith("/app1")],
});

registerApplication({
  name: "@mrc/app2",
  app: () => System.import("@mrc/app2"),
  activeWhen: ["/app2", (location) => location.pathname.startsWith("/app2")],
});

registerApplication({
  name: "@mrc/app3",
  app: () => System.import("@mrc/app3"),
  activeWhen: ["/"],
  customProps: {
    currentPath: window.location.pathname,
  },
});

start();
```

```
**app3.js**

import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import LeftPane from "./components/LeftPane/LeftPane";
import NavBody from "./components/NavBody/NavBody";

const App = ({ currentPath }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {typeof window !== "undefined" && currentpath !== "/" ? (
        <LeftPane />
      ) : null}
      {typeof window !== "undefined" && currentPath === "/" ? (
        <NavBody />
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The goal is LeftPane component from app3 should not be rendered only for path="/" and NavBody should be rendered only for path="/".
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the maintainers of `single-spa`. Thanks for pointing out an area of the documentation that could be more clear.

Custom props passed in from the `registerApplication` method are not "live" and do not update automatically. Luckily what you're trying to accomplish can be done in several different ways that will meet your needs.

Options:

1. Instead of passing down `window.location.pathname` from the `registerApplication` call. Just use it directly in `@mrc/app3`
2. Have app3 use a router of some sort (maybe react-router) and use the routes in there

There are a few other options as well but I think either of those would solve the issue you're facing.

`single-spa` is meant to be a top level router between microfrontends. Each microfrontend typically does it's own routing.

See [this example](https://react.microfrontends.app/) and how single-spa only handles the top level routes
[`planets` is active at `/planets`](https://github.com/react-microfrontends/root-config/blob/main/src/index.ejs#L31) and then the planets application does [routing internally](https://github.com/react-microfrontends/planets/blob/main/src/root.component.js#L7) to make components active at specific routes.

Comment: Here my app3 will be registered always. So if I implement route mech, will the app3 re-render itself based on route? since route doesnot cause a page reload right?